# Show by an explicit example that the function $h$ given is not injective and is surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, injective-module

I'm not to sure how to do this:

Show by an explicit example that the function $h$ given is not injective and is surjective.

$$h(m,n) = m+2n$$ where $m,n \in \mathbb Z$.

I thought maybe if I did
$h(5,-3)$ it might be the solution, but for injective I would get the same answer on both side meaning "it is" injective? 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to specify a codomain to talk about surjectivity. Given an integer domain, this will not be surjective with a real codomain.

Comment: Hint: (assuming $h:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\rightarrow\mathbb Z$) for surjectiveness $h(m,0) = m$ and for non injectiveness $(m,n)\neq(m-2k,n+k)$ but $h(m,n)=h(m-2k,n+k)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $h:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$. Write out the definition of injective, For all $(m,n)\in \mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ if $h(m_1,n_1)=h(m_2,n_2)$ then $(m_1,n_1)=(m_2,n_2)$. This is false for $h$ as you said, so give a counterexample. One would be, $h(2,0)=h(0,1)=2$ but $(2,0)\not=(0,1)$. Use the definition of surjective to prove the next statement, for any $y\in \mathbb Z$ there exists $(m,n)\in \mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ so that $h(m,n)=y$. An example would be for any $y \in \mathbb Z$ let $(m,n)=(y,0)$. Then $h(y,0)=y+2(0)=y$ so $h$ is surjective.

Comment: yes your rights it is $h:\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$. thank you for the answer the only part that i dont understand is the surjective. would you be able to explain that part a little bit more for me?

Comment: So the definition of surjective is that given a function $f: A \to B$, for every $y \in B$, there is an element $x \in A$ so that $f(x)=y$. In other words $f$ "maps" to the entire codomain. In this case $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is the domain and $\mathbb Z$ is the codomain. Since our codomain is infinite you must come up with a general formula or method to show that we can make any integer using the definition of $h$. Theres no one right answer, another way to do it would be given any $y\in\mathbb Z$ let $(m,n)=(-y,y)$. Then $(-y,y)\in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ and $h(-y,y)=-y+2y=y$

Comment: thank you very much, thanks for the answer and explanation.